# Service not found - postman

Tags: postman

I'm trying to send an api request with a header;

URL >> https://pos2.xxxxxxxx.com:8443/ua-mc/pos2

Header >> Authorization  `Basic Y29uZmlnLXN1cG8fn384nd8OWlqbkJHVDU=`

But it gives a response 'Service not found'.
What does this mean? Could it be a problem with the URL?

Comment: Can you share an image of Postman with the error please. What type of request is it - GET, POST etc. More details about what you’re trying to do and what you’ve tried already would be helpful.

Comment: thank you very much. But, I found the mistake. Solution is given below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution and the reason. My url was missing one part in the middle. It seems like you get this specific error when you don't have an end point defined by the url you provide and the port you are specifying.